# CKEditor problems updating texarea's value

Tags: jquery, textarea, ckeditor

In my php program I display input forms either regular way on page load or in a dialog box using ajax calls.

There are two methods to create a CKEditor from textarea. Either to use jQuery

```
$("#textareaid").ckeditor();
```

or

```
window["textareaid"] = CKEDITOR.replace("textareaid");
```

Both methods creates my rich text editor inplace of my textarea in both cases either on page load or after an ajax call. That's fine.

Here starts the problems. In these conditions CKEditor initiates without any console errors, but it never updates textarea value and always sends old value.

1) If I create my textarea on page load and use `$("#textareaid").ckeditor();`. CKEditor initiates ok without any console errors but on regular form submit, the sent value is empty (old value).

2) If I create my textarea after an ajax call and use `window["textareaid"] = CKEDITOR.replace("textareaid");` . Again CKEditor initiates correctly but if I do $("form").serialize() and alert the result I see that textarea value is empty (old value).

I can't create a demo page and upload right now and I know that no one will try to replicate this issue without my codes (at least I wouldn't because I'm so lazy)

I'll prepare a demo page to replicate this issue for you guys but until then I'm asking if someone here faced the same problem and know the reason or found a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Never had that problem. If you inspect the textarea with Firebug and type in the textarea at the same time, do you see your text being added in between the tags?

Comment: @Chris G. Neither on Chrome nor Firfox CKEditor never updates data between textarea tags. I checked also the actual sample files of CKEditor and they don't update too.

Comment: @ergec Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be ok if you call:

```
 CKEDITOR.instances[your instance].updateElement();
```

'your instance' in the eaxmple would be simply `textareaid` since that's what you're using in the `CKEDITOR.replace()` function

before you serialize the form.

Had the exact same problems a couple of days ago :)

Comment: mine still not working its saying " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateElement' of undefined "

Comment: @HabibRehman Sorry, but this answer is from October 2011... I think you should look into more current rich-text editors :)

Comment: Thank you.  This was exactly my problem.  I had just entered a serialize for ajax where I had been previously just sending the form via POST.  This was a hard to find error.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this same symptom and it seems to be tied to using an id to select the object for the textarea instead of name with jQuery adapter.
The reference material on the jQuery adapter does state that when it is a textarea it will automatically send this value back, so it may not validate correctly as a textarea with a jquery `$("#myTextarea").ckeditor();`

If you want to keep the id selector, an option is to use a hidden field with the final form field name that you send the value to when you submit the form.
    `$("#myHiddenField").val($("#myTextarea").val());`

Answer (score 0):

after loading editor by replace, you may add this line

```
CKEDITOR.instances.textAreaClientId.on('blur', function() CKEDITOR.instances.textAreaClientId.updateElement();});
```